# Selector to select third list item?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Suppose a HTML markup like this:

```
<ul>
    <li>List item 1</li>
    <li>List item 2</li>
    <li>List item 3</li><!-- I want to select only this -->
</ul>
```

Would it be possible to select only the third list item in the unordered list element? I've been browsing the jQuery documentation but I can't find any selector that could do this.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You may want to use the [nth-child selector](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/)

```
$('ul li:nth-child(3)')
```

Answer (score 4):

```
$("ul li:eq(2)") // 3rd item
```

http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/

Comment: This doesn't work but the Neil's answer worked. Thanks anyways :)

Comment: @Richard There are some subtle differences between :eq and :nth-child which are worth reading about in the docs.

:eq would work for this but may need to be tweaked slightly.

Answer (score 0):

here you go

```
$('ul>li').each(function(i){
    if(i == 2)
    {
       //your code goes here

       return;
    } 
});
```

cheers

Comment: jquery is much more powerful than that.

Comment: but this can give you more then 3rd result which sometimes can be better for performance... cheers